# Line fit algorithm/package to use in R that will satisfy certain criteria

Tags: python, r, excel, algorithm

I have a specific problem where I need a equation fit to a set of data where I can extract a general function (can be complex) that will give me a Y value that is very close to the data as possible-- as if I used the data as a lookup table.

I have been reading up on various approaches and Multivariate adaptive regression splines [MARS] seemed like an excellent candidate. The problem I have is that it is not detecting/fitting a hinge at a very important segment of the data.

I'm primarily using R with the Earth package, with the intention to put an equation in to Excel. I can use other languages or packages if it will give me the results I need.

PROBLEM:
At the low end of my data I have a small set of values that are an important lower bound that need to have a hinge or knot placed.

The rest of the data should have automatic hinge/knot detection.

Example:
X     Y
0     130
1     130
10000 130
rest of X past 10000 with increasing Y's at various rates.

It will average the 0 through 10,000 range into the increasing Y values where if I
predict(model, 5000) I may get say 150 as a result. The line needs a flat linear segment, then hinge at 10000. This lack of a hinge causes all the high values of X to be very accurate in the MARS model output but the low values of X to diverge significantly from the base data.

I would rather not manually place this as the lower end may change and I would like a generalized approach.

Does anyone know of an approach similar to MARS that can provide

1. Automatic knot/hinge detection
2. Output is an equation I could place in to Excel
3. If the automatic detection is failing on an important section the ability to manually specify a point to hinge on.

The MARS approach is working for all the other breakpoints in the data but because of the limited "range" of the lower bound it doesn't place a hinge there even with pruning turned off.

Does anyone know of a better approach?

Comment: you can try polynomial regression if all you want is best fit with no theory

Comment: you can also try the `segmented` library in R which lets you specify how many breaks you want (for segmented linear model) and where you want them.  However, I have run into similar problems where I cant get breaks where I want them.  I think the algorithm that finds breakpoints runs into problems when there is too much correlation between the sections.

Comment: Don't use Excel.  Ever.   If you've got R, why on earth go to the 5th level of Hell?